# Get_dummies produces more columns than its supposed to

Tags: pandas

I'm using get_dummies on a column of data that has zeroes or 'D' or "E". Instead of producing 2 columns it produces 5 - C, D, E, N, O. I'm not sure what they are and how to make it do just 2 as its supposed to.

When I just pull that column shows 0's and D and E, but when I put it in get_dummies adds extra columns

```
data[[2]]
0
0
D
0
0
0
0
D
0
0
```

When I do this:

```
dummy = pd.get_dummies(data[2], dummy_na = False)
dummy.head()
```

I get

```
0 C D E N O PreferredContactTime
0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

What are C , N and O? I don't understand what it is displaying at all.

Comment: `pd.get_dummies(s)` always gives a dataframe whose columns are `s.unique()`. Did you check `data[2].unique()`?

Comment: What is `data[2].dtype`? I'm guessing `category` so you're getting dummies for unused categories

Answer (score 4):

### Setup

```
dtype = pd.CategoricalDtype([0, 'C', 'D', 'E', 'N', 'O', 'PreferredContactTime'])

data = pd.DataFrame({2: [
    'PreferredContactTime', 0, 0, 'D', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'D', 0, 0
]}).astype(dtype)
```

---

Your result

```
dummy = pd.get_dummies(data[2], dummy_na=False )
dummy.head()

   0  C  D  E  N  O  PreferredContactTime
0  0  0  0  0  0  0                     1
1  1  0  0  0  0  0                     0
2  1  0  0  0  0  0                     0
3  0  0  1  0  0  0                     0
4  1  0  0  0  0  0                     0
```

Comment: Right, so moral of the story: Use `remove_unused_categories` to remove categories that aren't actually in the data. `pd.get_dummies(data[2].cat.remove_unused_categories(), dummy_na=False )` (or just convert to string, whichever works).

Comment: ya , i just got rid of them . just not sure why they showed up there to startwith..